# Show that $-1=\sum_{0}^{\infty} (p-1)p^i$ in $\mathbf{Q}_p$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

To show that in the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$, where $p$ is a prime, it holds that: $$-1=\sum_{0}^{\infty} (p-1)p^i$$ I did the following:

It suffices to show that:

$\left|\sum_0^N (p-1)p^i+1 \right|_p \to 0, \text{ when } n \to +\infty$

For each non-negative integer $N$,

$\sum_{0}^N (p-1)p^i=\sum_{0}^N (p^{i+1}-p^i)=p^{N+1}-1$

Thus: $\left| \sum_{0}^{N} (p-1)p^i-(-1)\right|_p=|p^{N+1}-1+1|_p=|p^{N+1}|_p=p^{-(N+1)} \to 0, \text{ when } N \to +\infty$

But the prof said that we cannot do it like that since we can't conclude from $|a_n|_p \to 0$ that $a_n \to 0$. How else could we do it?

Comment: I don't get it: isn't **the definition**  $$\;\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\iff \lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|_p=0\;??$$

Comment: @Timbuc That's certainly not a definition.

Comment: Ok...not that that helped a lot, not to mention that some books and internet sites seem to say otherwise, but ok.

Comment: Do you have an idea @AlexR ?

Comment: @evinda , have you checked out the definition of the p-adic integers as a completion of $\mathbb{Z}$ at the ideal generated by the prime number $p$? One can define the $p$-adic numbers also in this algebraic way, and then the thing you are trying to prove is immediate. But if you're unfamiliar with this thing it might only make things more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all $\sum_{0}^{\infty} p^i = \frac{1}{1-p}$. Indeed, as $(1-p) \sum_{0}^{N} p^i = 1 - p^{N+1}$ and as $p^{N+1}\to 0$ in $\mathbf{Q}_p$ as $N\to +\infty$, we have  $\sum_{0}^{\infty} p^i = \frac{1}{1-p}$.

Now : $\sum_{0}^{\infty} (p-1)p^i = (p-1) \sum_{0}^{\infty} p^i = (p-1) \frac{1}{1-p} = -1$ in $\mathbf{Q}_p$

Comment: I got it!!! Thanks a lot!!! :-)

Comment: Could I also ask you something else? If we want to find the 5-adic expansion of $\frac{3}{8}$ could we do it as follows?

$$\frac{3}{8}=\frac{3}{(-4)(-2)}=\frac{-3}{2} \frac{1}{1-5}=-\frac{3}{2} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 5^i$$

Comment: Or is it like that? :/

$$\frac{3}{8}=1-\frac{5}{8}=1-\frac{10}{4}=1+10 \frac{1}{1-5}=1+10 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 5^i=1+10(1+5+5^2+5^3+ \dots)=11+10 \cdot 5+ 10 \cdot 5^2+ \dots$$

Comment: @evinda No, both are not expansion of $\frac{3}{8}$. An expansion of $\frac{3}{8}$ is $\frac{3}{8} = \sum_{k\geq k_0} \alpha_k p^k$ for some $k_0\in\mathbf{Z}$ and the $\alpha_k$'s in $\{0,\ldots,p-1\}$. For a very nice practical tutorial on expansion, see : http://cs.ucsb.edu/~koc/docs/r09.pdf